# Background.js listener not working in chrome extension on ".then" statement

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth

Here's my code in App.js (simplified it).
I am getting the `data` and I can read the user data when I console.

However, my listener in my background.js does not respond to it.

```
chrome.identity
            .launchWebAuthFlow({ url: authURL, interactive: true })
            .then((responseUrl) => {
                fetch(userInfoEndpoint)
                    .then((response) => response.json())
                    .then((data) => {
                        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                            type: 'setUser',
                            user: data,
                        });
                    })
```

Here's my listener:

// In background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.type === 'setUser') {
        chrome.storage.local.set({ user: message.user });
    }
});
```

If I run it just above the fetch function with dummy data, the listener detects the change.

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    type: 'setUser',
    user: data,
});
```

Just not if its inside the `fetch .then` statement.

Additionally, a button triggers this, that's in my extension popup.
If I have the popup inspected (its console open), it sends the message fine and then it works even inside the `then` statement.

Some people say use `persistent` for the background script, but I can't as this is manifest v3.

Comment: 1) Simply store the data using chrome.storage inside `then` instead of messaging. 2) If this code is inside the popup, it may close when the interactive sign-in UI opens. In this case you need to put your entire chrome.identity code inside the background script.

Comment: I did the messaging because storing the code wasn't working in the popup.
So I actually moved my fetch code using a message to background.js and that worked.

But I'll still keep this open to see if there are any other ways to avoid doing that.

Comment: Assuming the popup is closed, this is the only way, because when the popup closes its code is immediately terminated, so its callbacks/thens won't run.

Comment: @wOxxOm The code is running in my extension popup. The popup remains open, still doesn't work.

However if I inspect the popup, while its open, then it works.

Now sure why inspecting it makes a difference.

Comment: Then it's either a bug in Chrome or there's another problem in the code that's not shown.